# How do you construct a typedef to rmember method

Tags: c++, typedef

Win7

cygwin gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 64-bits (2000 C++)

I'm trying to construct a typedef to a member function:

```
class MyClass {
   typedef int32_t (*func1)(class const * const name);
   typedef int32_t (func2)(class const * const name);
public:
   int32_t memberFunc(class const * const name);
}
MyClass:: someFunc() {
func1 x, y;
x = &memberFunc; // error: address of non-static member illegal
y = memberFunc;  // error: conversion error

func2 z;
z = memberFunc; // error: invalid use of member function
}
```

I've looked at previous posts and they indicate that the func1 definition is correct and that the assignment (x = &memberFunc) is also correct - at least for non-member functions. I would prefer not making memberFunc static if I can. So, any good examples and any good explanations?

thanks
art

Comment: Look at the one with `y`'s error message and see which type it expects. For `x`, it should be `&MyClass::memberFunc`, and then you'll probably get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, a member function receives one more parameter: `this` pointer. So normal function-pointer and member function-pointer is different. member function-poineter syntax is like the following:

```
typedef int32_t (MyClass::*func1)(MyClass const * const name);
```

and It is used as follows:

```
func1 f = &MyClass::memberFunc;

MyClass c;
MyClass *pc = &c;
(c.*f)(nullptr);
(pc->*f)(nullptr);
```

PS. `class const * const name` <-- you've mistyped? I think not class, but MyClass

edit: You can use `std::bind` as follows:

```
MyClass c;
auto f = std::bind(&MyClass::memberFunc, &c /*this pointer*/);
```

In this, `f` is NOT member function-pointer, but binder function-object.

Answer (score 0):

**Function pointers cannot bind to *member* functions.**

You need a pointer-to-member-function, or something easier to use like `std::function` and a call to `std::bind`.

Comment: I won't go into long detail because this topic has been covered a-plenty on Stack Overflow before. There are literally hundreds of questions on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need what is known as a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) for this to work.

Effectively, the address of your function is insufficient to call a non-static class function, because instantiated objects have non-local storage. Thus, to actually call a member function, you need a `this` pointer as well.

It has been explained elsewhere, but I figured I would throw in the technical term. Anything that wraps the function address and the necessary parameters (namely a `this` pointer) to satisfy the calling convention for a class function is an implementation of a closure.